# How to use padding and lengthen bootstrap search bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to using bootstrap and I'm wondering how to extend the length of the search bar.

I'm trying to create a simplified version of the Google homepage but the bootstrap search box is much smaller than that of Google.

Does anyone know how to increase the width of the search box?

Also, how would I add padding around my Google logo?

I've tried add padding-top to .logo {} in CSS but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">
    <head> 
        <title>Simple Google Homepage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/google_homepage.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar-navbar-inverse-navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="Simple Google Homepage"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/up/accounts/upgrade/?continue=https://plus.google.com/u/0/?gpsrc%3Dogpy0%26tab%3DwX&gpsrc=ogpy0">+You</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="images.google.com">Images</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blank"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="mail.google.com">example@gmail.com</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">

                </div>

                </div>
        </div>


        <div class = "logo" align = "center">
            <img src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class = "Google" width= "269" height = "95">

                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">

                </div>
                </form>



        </div>

    </body


</html>
```

Feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your css:

```
#srch-term {
  width: 800px;
}
```

You can change the width to whatever you'd like.

Comment: that didn't seem to work. Could it be that my css isn't linked correctly in my  html? or something along those lines?

Comment: try doing a display:none on the #srch-term element. If it doesn't disappear then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS part to the head and change accordingly.

```
<style>
    .logo{
        padding-top: 150px;
    }
    .input-group{
        padding: 10px;
        width: 40%;
    }
</style>
```

But be care full if you are adding another input-group then have a Id.